# How to include @Autowired for dynamically invoked methods

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am having a class(Service layer) which creates class instance dynamically and calls the method- `model.getClassInstance().method();`,this method intern calls one more method which is abstract and implemented in inherited classes.
Inherit class contains @autowired to access DB but since this class is called by instantiating like `new Object()` i am unable to autowire the fields(NullPointer exception).

So is there any way to autowire the field without having **@Service or @Controller or @Component?**?

I tried by adding the inherited class to **spring-servlet.xml** as bean but no use.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible to create that object using spring beans instead of new object? because then spring will have no control over this object.

If that's not an option, then you can do this by making use of `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` and calling `autowireBean(Object existingBean)` on you're object. This method makes the object treat as if Spring created it.

```
private @Autowired AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory;

public void func() 
{
   Employee employee = // Dynamically loaded object.

   // After this below line, employee object will have its dependecies injected.
   autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(employee);
}
```